# HTTP: Why do you need to specify hostname?

Tags: http

I'm starting to learn sockets, and I'm trying to figure out why you need to specify the hostname in the request. If I am already connected to "www.google.com", then what is the point of "Host: www.google.com\r\n" in the request? Doesn't the server already know its own name?

Comment: This is really about HTTP protocol, not winsock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes the server does know its hostname, but it isn't always a 1:1 relationship. Many DNS hostnames can all point to the same IP, thus, 1 IP can have many DNS hostnames. (Also, a single DNS hostname can map to many IP addresses, but this is less important in this question.)

The `Host:` line in an HTTP request allows a web server to know which hostname you requested, and serve based on that. This allows one machine at an IP address to serve many domains.

For example, if a webserver sees `Host: foo.com`, it might serve one website, but `Host: bar.com` might result in a completely different result being returned. There is no other piece of data available to the webserver with this information, and it relies on the web client to inform it.

Answer (score 3):

A given server can have many different DNS names. Think shared hosting sites for example.

Comment: Shared hosting sites often use virtual machines, so you do get one machine for yourself. However, DNS names are mapped to IP addresses, so "server" isn't a relevant concept here.